# 785GB ioDrive Mono MLC PCIe Solid State Storage Card with Poweredge R730

Tags: dell-poweredge

Has anyone used a 785GB ioDrive Mono MLC PCIe Solid State Storage Card with a PowerEdge R730.The chances are slim, Dell say they have never tested this.

http://accessories.euro.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=bsd&cs=ukbsdt1&sku=414-10021 does not mention in the product compatibility.

Yet sandisk say they are compatible but was that just a brochure typo http://www.sandisk.co.uk/assets/docs/dell-enterprise-ssd-and-pcie-datasheet.pdf

It is not a standard set up I know, but due to the cards being slightly old but it will save me £30K if some has this configuration that works.

Comment: I have two shine new Poweredge R730 and some older 785GB ioDrive Mono MLC PCIe Solid State Storage Cards they come in at £10K each card, If i can use them in the shine servers I would but Dell can't help but I was wondering if anyone has experiences this particular set up. it is not a request product, service, or learning material recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Officially it's not listed as compatible.

In dell system builder for OEM vendor it would not be available too, to add to an PowerEdge 730.

Please contact your Dell re-vendor in case they can do a special deal for you to test it.

Overview

The Power Distribution Unit (PDUs) are premium solutions to many of the power management problems seen in today's IT environments. Some of the problems are unauthorized use of power outlets, locked-up equipment, in-rush current, overloaded circuits, and the need of remote access to power outlets in the rack. The PDUs address these problems through individual outlet control, power on and off delays, current monitoring, alarm thresholds, and network management.

Compatible With :

**PowerEdge Rack Black Ship**

Manufacturer Part : CG10J
Dell Part : 414-10021

Compatibility
This product is compatible with the following systems:
**PowerEdge M610x
PowerEdge R610
PowerEdge R620
PowerEdge R710
PowerEdge R720
Poweredge R720xd
PowerEdge R810
PowerEdge R820
PowerEdge R910
PowerEdge T620**

Comment: I have also found this http://www.sandisk.co.uk/assets/docs/dell-enterprise-ssd-and-pcie-datasheet.pdf which indicates that scan disk think it is compatible !!

Comment: @icecurtain I would test, as its in the same serie, but as it cost hight, I dont want to give you a bad advice